# NodeJS: Rapidly converting image with Data URI causes caching, memory leak

Tags: node.js, image, memory-leaks

I am working on a software which reads a high amount of images and do processing on those images like reading their height, width etc.
I came to see a very difficult situation where the memory used during converting the image url into Data URI.

```
request.get(imageUrl, function (error, my_data, body) {
    var imageBase64Data = new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
    var imageData = "data:" + my_data.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + imageBase64Data;
    // using the imageData in image processing using GraphicsMagick module
});
```

Now the problem i am facing is when my node process starts to run and process these images, it quickly get the memory used upto 1.7GB.
And the system starts giving error of memory.

I checked and learned that the buffer used to convert the image url into the Data URI does not deletes the memory once it is out of scope.

Please suggest or help how should i go further to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this translates to what you are using buffer with base64 encoding. But this is how I translate buffer works.
When you create a new buffer it increased the heapTotal and heapUsed. Though this does not translate to the number of blocks being used.  Deleting the buffer does reduce the size of the heap but not in proportion to the number of blocks that were used in the buffer. I would suggest that after you've consumed it, try and set the imageBase64Data = null. Node's internal GC will free up those blocks in the next sweep.

Also, since the variables are declared inside your request callback handler anonymous function every time you make a request it's creating a new imageBase64Data, imageData in memory. If you declare it outside the request and reference it inside your new data may overwrite the value. But you would also need to be careful as you will be mutating the values inside the function. If you want to maintain referenced to processed url's then I would suggest looking into memonizing or caching so you don't process the same url again and again.

*Here's a simple test which shows you how GC works when you set the buffer to null.*

```
→ node                    
> process.memoryUsage()
{ rss: 21639168, heapTotal: 10522624, heapUsed: 5058760 }
> mybuf = require('buffer').Buffer
{ [Function: Buffer]
  poolSize: 8192,
  from: [Function],
  alloc: [Function],
  allocUnsafe: [Function],
  allocUnsafeSlow: [Function],
  isBuffer: [Function: isBuffer],
  compare: [Function: compare],
  isEncoding: [Function],
  concat: [Function],
  byteLength: [Function: byteLength] }
> var buf = new mybuf(56789)
undefined
> process.memoryUsage()
{ rss: 24563712, heapTotal: 11571200, heapUsed: 6459632 }
> buf = null
null
> process.memoryUsage()
{ rss: 24756224, heapTotal: 11571200, heapUsed: 6591688 }
> process.memoryUsage()
{ rss: 24805376, heapTotal: 11571200, heapUsed: 6637832 }
> process.memoryUsage()
{ rss: 23359488, heapTotal: 8425472, heapUsed: 5567208 }
>
```

Note: [Nodejs 6.10.2](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/buffer.html) states that creating a buffer using

`new Buffer(body)` is deprecated.